# Spring JPA Save entity with @JoinColumn

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have two entities

**Entity 1**

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "Table1")
    public class Table1{
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "Table1_SEQ", sequenceName = "Table1_SEQ", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "Table1_SEQ")
    @Column(name = "seq", updatable = false, unique = true, insertable = true)
    private Long seq;
    @Column(name = "number", updatable = false, insertable = true)
    private Long number;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "enumber", updatable = false, insertable = true)
    private Table2 table2;
```

**Entity 2**

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "Table2")
    public class Table2 {
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "Table2_SEQ", sequenceName = "Table2_SEQ", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "Table2_SEQ")
    @Column(name = "enumber")
    private Long eNumber;
```

I have a repository which extends **JpaRepository**

```
public interface Table1Repository extends JpaRepository<Table1, Long> {

}
```

When I try to save using

```
Table1Repository rep;
Table1 table1; // Assume this is initialized correctly
rep.save(table1);
```

I get a Foriegn Key constraint error *org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException*

Table1 has a Foreign Key association with Table2 on the column **enumber** but I don't want to insert anything into Table2.

**How do I save into Table1?**

I'm not too familiar with Jpa so please let me know if you need any clarifications on what I'm asking or if you need any more information.

Answer (score 0):

```
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "enumber", updatable = false, insertable = true)
    private Table2 table2; // THIS IS WRONG!

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "enumber", updatable = false, insertable = true)
    private Long enumberFKTable2; // THIS IS CORRECT!

   //getters and setters
```

### Implement another java class similar to table1 called table2 with all the spring annotations. Then you do the following code:

```
//First, make sure that the foreign key exists!
number enumber = entityManager.getReference(Enumber.class, enumberId);

//test

if(enumber != null){
Table 1 table1 = new Table1();
table1.setEnumber(enumber);
entityManager.persist(table1);
}
```

Comment: I have the foreign key set correctly in table1.getTable2().getEnumber().

Comment: So, just copy the code above and try it. You first need to retrieve the enumber object from DB and then set as parameter in the table1 object then persist.

Comment: I'm a bit confused here. Table1 does not have a property called **enumber** for me to do `table1.setEnumber(enumber)`. Do you mean to say I need to add a new property in my Table1 entity along with
`Table2 table2` property

Comment: I have entity Table2 up in my question. If I remove
`private Table2 table2;` and replace it with
`private Long enumberFKTable2;`, how do I create an association between the two tables?